# Bathroom Shower

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I need to reconnect my shower drain and the pipe that connects downstairs? How do I know what materials to get and how do I fix it?

Comment: while most plumbing drain sizes are standard, there are some variations as to the method of connection. Please attach a few pictures of your problem. Be sure to add dimensions if possible.

Comment: How would we know if we can't see what you have to work with already? Pls. include some pix of the existing drain pipes, etc.

Comment: It might also help if you explained how it became disconnected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.